# Basic Java and Eclipse

Tags: java

Make a util class with three methods. First method's name is add, that returns the result by adding two numbers.

Second method's name is multiply, that returns the result by multiplying two numbers.

Third's method name is division that returns a result by dividing first parameter by second parameter.

Then call a method from this class called main and print the results 6 times for each method call? I'm having trouble with this part.

This is what I've got so far:

```
public class Util {
    public static int add(int a, int b) {
        int result = a + b;
        System.out.println("result = " + result);

        return result;
    }

    public static int multiply(int a, int b) {
        int result = a * b;
        System.out.println("result = " + result);

        return result;
    }

    public static int divide(int a, int b) {
        int result = a / b;
        System.out.println("result = " + result);

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int res = multiply(5, 2);
        System.out.println("res = " + res);

        res = add(5, 2);
        System.out.println("res = " + res);

        res = divide(5, 2);
        System.out.println("res = " + res);
    }
}
```

How would I do this:  call a method from this class called main and print the results 6 times for each method call?

Comment: You are calling the methods already in your main method. Just do it 6 times each?

Answer (score 0):

just use a for loop like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        System.out.println(multiply(5, 2));
        System.out.println(add(5, 2));
        System.out.println(divide(5, 2));
    }
}
```

or from another class:

```
public class Main()
{

private Util myUtil;

public void calculate()
{

    for (int i = 0; i <= 6; i++) {
        System.out.println(myUtil.multiply(5, 2));
        System.out.println(myUtil.add(5, 2));
        System.out.println(myUtil.divide(5, 2));
    }

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main myMain = new Main();
    myMain.calculate();
}
```

Comment: But how would I call it from a class?

Comment: Thanks Krelos but why do we use private Util myUtil; and {
this.myUtil = new Util();

Comment: you create a new instance of your Util class, which u can use then. Since your methods are static you don't need the new Utils() part. Just google for  basic object orientated programming in java and you will find a lot of tutorials and simple explanations with code snippets :)